# Rxjava not working after releasing

Tags: android, apk, rx-java

I am using rxjava in my app, it works fine when I test in, but when I try to run the signed apk file in my android devices, the app crashed when it comes to the code of rxjava, I have added this in proguard-rules,but the app still crashed , anyone has idea of the reason? This is the crash information.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
    at e.bb.c(Unknown Source)
    at e.bb.(Unknown Source)
    at e.ar.a(Unknown Source)
    at e.ay.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at $Proxy1.a(Native Method)
    at com.kinnov.onlineordering.LoginFragment.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.kinnov.onlineordering.LoginFragment.loginTapped(Unknown Source)
    at com.kinnov.onlineordering.bq.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick(Unknown Source)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4444)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18440)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is the proguard-rules

```
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.ImmediateScheduler {
    public <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.TestScheduler {
    public <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.subscriptions.Subscriptions{
    public static <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.exceptions.Exceptions{
    public static <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static ** test();
}
-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
       long producerIndex;
       long consumerIndex;
      }
-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef {
        long producerNode;
         long consumerNode;
      }
-keep class rx.operators.OperationReplay* {
    *;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/RxJavaProGuardRules/blob/master/rxjava-proguard-rules/proguard-rules.txt

```
-dontwarn sun.misc.**

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
    long producerIndex;
    long consumerIndex;
 }

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef {
    rx.internal.util.atomic.LinkedQueueNode producerNode;
 }

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueConsumerNodeRef { 
   rx.internal.util.atomic.LinkedQueueNode consumerNode;
 }
```

You left out the last rule I believe.